# react useEffect(): Hello only logs one time

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I wonder why 'Hello' is only logged once, since there is setCounter(1) which will trigger re-render, for me 'Hello' will be logged twice.
Maybe there is something to do with the dependency array? Since props.visible is not passed, useEffect() will only run one time?

Here is my CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-brattain-hw0mm?file=/src/App.js:23-287

Any help is appreciated.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

    export default function App(props) {
      const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Hello");
        setCounter(1);
      }, [props.visible]);
      return <div className="App">{counter}</div>;
    }
```

Comment: an effect will run every time it detects a dependency has changed. In your example setting counter to 1 does not change the value of `props.visible`, hence the effect will not re-trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function inside `useEffect` runs one time on initial render and then every time when the value(s) in dependency array change. If `props.visible` doesn't change the useEffect is not triggered even if the component rerendered due to state change.

Answer (score 2):

The `props.visible` comes from the parent component so that added depedecy array in `useEffect` if `props.visible` change then `useEffect` call again.

If you add `counter` as a dependency array and change the `counter` value so `useEffect` will called.

**Example :**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App(props) {
   const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

   useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Hello");
   }, [counter]);

  return (
   <div className="App">
     {counter}
    <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)} > Increment </button>

   </div>;
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, props.visible does not change, that is why, if you pass in counter as a dependency to the useEffect, then you should see the output on each change of the counter. (in your case, once more)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in thinking that the dependency array is the cause of the issue.

If you supply values within the dependency array, then react will only re-render if the supplied values are changed. You have supplied `prop.visible`, which doesn't update nor cause a re-render to occur.

For this example to be correct then your code would need to look like this:

```
export default function App(props) {
      const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Hello");
        setCounter(1);
      }, [counter]);
      return <div className="App">{counter}</div>;
    }
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html